# C string program

Tags: c, string

I have been given a task at school to write a program that

- Reads three strings
- Stores the third string in dynamically allocated memory
- Print out the last 4 letters of the first word alphabetically.

Here is the program I have so far. The strings are all stored in different variables, making them hard to sort. If anyone could give me a hand and help me finish this program, I would be very grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char word1[101];
   char word2[101];
   char* word3;
   char buffer[101];
   scanf("%s", word1);
   scanf("%s", word2);
   scanf("%s", buffer);
   word3 = (char *) malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
   strcpy(word3, buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a homework question with actual code!

Comment: `scanf( "%s", word )` is unsafe.  You are asking for a buffer overflow error.  Simply enter a string that exceeds 100 characters and BOOM--buffer overflow.  Limit the max size of the scan with `scanf( "%100s", word )`.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#Security for more info.

Comment: Also be careful with `strcpy`--this function is the cause of many buffer overflow vulnerabilities.  Consider using  `strncpy`, which limits the maximum size of the string, instead.  Even still, with `strncpy` the final character copied is not guaranteed to be `\x00`, so be sure to set the final character after you copy the data.  Losing string terminators can cause major headaches.

Comment: Note that you can safely ignore suggestions to use complicated sorting algorithms. A naive sorting implemenation will be good enough for your purposes - you're only sorting 4 characters!

Comment: This is a homework question, not a essay on security flaws.

Comment: @graham.needs - whilst I agree with your point, any opportunity to educate someone who's learning to program in ways to do so more securely can never be a bad thing =)

Comment: The use of strcpy in this case looks fine for me.

Comment: @Nyan, with the unsafe `scanf`, `strcpy` is also unsafe here.  If the `scanf` was done safely, `strcpy` would be safe.  I prefer to never use `strcpy` in my code because it fosters awareness of buffer sizes that is easily lost.

Comment: @graham.needs, if you never learn bad habits, you don't have to break them.  Buffer overflows are common and so heavily exploited.  IOM, it is critical that new C programmers be taught to avoid them rather than forced to figure it out on their own.  My education did not include such "minor" considerations--it was "academically pure".  As a result, I wrote exploitable code until I found information about the dangers of these functions.  If I wasn't such a geek, reading articles all the time, then I'd still be writing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`strcmp() function`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/strcmp) to compare the strings.

Also, don't forget to clean up the memory pointed to by `word3` using the `free()` function before you are finished.

Comment: Thanks, how would i use strcmp on the three strings though? sorry i am new to this

Answer (score 2):

Use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) to find the first word alphabetically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char word1[101];
   char word2[101];
   char* word3;
   char buffer[101];
   scanf("%s", word1);
   scanf("%s", word2);
   scanf("%s", buffer);

   char* smallestword = word1;
   if (strcmp(smallestword,word2) > 0) // smallest is bigger than word2
     smallestword = word2;
   if (strcmp(smallestword,buffer) > 0) // smallest is bigger than buffer
     smallestword = buffer;

   word3 = (char *) malloc(strlen(smallestword)+1);
   strcpy(word3, buffer);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i am aware that i have to do this. But i need help implementing it

Comment: The link he provided shows examples of how to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats the code i had in mind, just wasnt quite sure how to write it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the program including code to get the substring of the last 4 characters of the smallest word. Also fixed a bug where `word3` was always set to the last word input (`buffer`), not `smallestword` as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
char word1[101]; 
char word2[101]; 
char* word3; 
char buffer[101];

scanf("%s", word1); 
scanf("%s", word2); 
scanf("%s", buffer);

char* smallestword = word1; 
if (strcmp(smallestword,word2) > 0) // smallest is bigger than word2
        smallestword = word2; 
if (strcmp(smallestword,buffer) > 0) // smallest is bigger than buffer
        smallestword = buffer;

word3 = (char *) malloc(strlen(smallestword)+1); 
strcpy(word3, smallestword);

int m = strlen( word3 ), n = m - 4;    // set offsets for substr
char* word3_substr = (char *) malloc(m-n); 
strncpy( word3_substr, word3+n, m-1 );

printf( "%s", word3_substr );

return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generalize, building an array of pointers and sorting it with a minimal bubble sort algorithm (or using qsort in the stdlib, better since you've not to extracode), if in ascending order, then first pointer points to the string you need. Even if it's homework, I think you should generalize (what if words are 4, or 5...?) and learn how to generalize such tasks.

```
 char *ptrs[] = { word1, word2, NULL };
 // later you initilize third too
 ptrs[2] = word3;
 // use qsort with strcmp as comp. function
 qsort(ptrs, sizeof(void *), 3, mwstrcmp);
 // ...
 // pick firts ptr
 char *first = ptrs[0];
 // print last 4 chars, see other answers or:
 // an alternative naive way of getting last 4 chars printed
 int l = strlen(first);
 char *fourstr = first;
 if ( l > 4 ) fourstr += l - 4;
 printf("%s", fourstr); // if length is < 4, it prints the whole string.
```

EDIT

`mwstrcmp` is a wrapper that dereference the pointers, since qsort passes pointers to the object (which are pointers...):

```
int mwstrcmp(const char **a, const char **b)
{
  return strcmp(*a, *b);
}
```

(warnings are possible too lazy to check now...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort strings, then first stores them into an array and make a [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You can also use this algorithm to sort strings in your linked list.